# How do I measure latency between Bluemix and my on-prem systems?

Tags: ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

I have an app running in Bluemix on a node.js runtime and I want to integrate it with APIs exposed by my on-prem system -- which is connected via the Secure Gateway.  What is the best way to measure the latency between Bluemix and my on-prem system to determine viability of this architecture?

Comment: "The best way" is going to net you downvotes and/or question closure because it's not definitive, but instead a discussion. You can ask "what are some ways to measure...", though.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you will get away with using ping nor traceroute.  Ping uses ICMP which is probably blocked by the BSO firewall.  As for traceroute, its not dependable and deprecated.
It might be possible to use snort to gain more insights into the latency times between your on-premises resources and Bluemix.